# How to load content on touches or mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html

How to load an `HTML` content on mouseover or `touchmove` with the help of javascript?

For example, I want to load the whole `<div id="mydiv">` content only when the user mouse over it.

```html
<div id="mydiv"> 
    <p>content</p> 
    <span> something </span> 
</div>
```

I want it to improve performance on page speed score. By using CSS it's not helpful

Comment: Is part of the content hidden by default then? I'd suggest using CSS for this. Research the `:hover` selector. Also note that this would be showing/hiding content, not technically loading content.

Comment: you should manage show/hide , no need to load content.

Comment: I want it for better performance with javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Try it by using CSS opacity

```css
#mydiv:hover {
  opacity: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mydiv {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" > 
  <p>content</p> 
  <span> something </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a smooth transition:

```
#mydiv {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

#mydiv:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

<div id="mydiv"> 
    <p>content</p> 
    <span> something </span> 
</div>
```